# Laravel 5.4: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to move a file which will be uploaded to public/foldername but i get this error of failed to open stream: Permission denied. 
Kindly tell me how to solve this error

Code of file uploading

```
    if(!empty($rep))
        {
            foreach($rep as $rep)
            {
                $filename = $rep->getClientOriginalName();
                $fileSize = $rep->getClientSize();
                $rep->storeAs('public/reportAttachment',$filename);
                $reportId = Report::where('reportId',$request->reportId)->first();
                $reportA = new ReportAttachment;
                $reportA->reportAttachmentFile = $filename;
                $reportA->report_id = $reportId->id;
                $reportA->save();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions for directories "storage", "public" and "reportAttachment". 
If not set to 777, set them chmod to 777.

Via ssh type in parent directory where storage is

```
ls -ld
```

for storage directory, you should be having

```
drwxrwxrwx
```

If not, change it to 777

```
sudo chmod -R storage
```

or more specific

```
sudo chmod 777 -R storage/public
```

If that doesn't solve the issue, there might be missing directory "reportAttachment"

If that doesn't solve the issue, check if public directory in storage is linked correctly

If that doesn't solve the issue, then check if file gets saved at all.

Comment: can you please tell me how to check and change permissions

Comment: @NidaAkram, I have expanded my answer